# Update last_edit with a middleware in Mongoose and Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Let's consider this schema:

```
var elementSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  last_edit: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
```

Now, every time I update any element.`name` I would like that mongoose updates directly the `last_edit` time.

In [Mongoose Middleware docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) it says:

```
var schema = new Schema(..);
schema.pre('save', function (next) {
  // do stuff
  next();
});
```

I might update it instead of `// do stuff`, however the document to be saved is not passed,
any hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `'save'` middleware, `this` is a reference to the document being saved:

```
schema.pre('save', function (next) {
  this.last_edit = Date.now();
  next();
});
```